# How to move created li after the last li from my ul in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var list = document.getElementById('mylist');
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode("My Tabs"));
entry.setAttribute("id", "last_tab");
list.appendChild(entry);
```

It creates a li and it put it as first and I wanted to be as the last element from my ul . How can do it from just javascript?

Thx

Comment: Could you please add your html here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code adds the new "li" element as the last element of the current list:

```js
var list = document.getElementById('mylist');
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode("My Tabs"));
entry.setAttribute("id", "last_tab");
list.appendChild(entry);
```

```html
<ul id="mylist">
<li>current li 1</li>
<li>current li 2</li>
</ul>
```

And this adds as the first element by using the JQuery library:

```js
var list = document.getElementById('mylist');
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode("My Tabs"));
entry.setAttribute("id", "last_tab");
$("#mylist").prepend(entry);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mylist">
<li>current li 1</li>
<li>current li 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
el.appendChild(el1)
```

Insert element (el1) as last child of parent node(el). To insert it as FIRST, you should call for `el.insertBefore(el1, child1)`. Something like 
`el.insertBefore(el1, el.querySelector('*'));`